# Visual effect view fine in Interface Builder, incorrect when app runs

Tags: ios, ios12, uivisualeffectview

I've got a visual effect view (light), and it displays perfectly fine on Interface Builder (blends the orange-ish background perfectly as it should):

[image]

However, when I run the app, this is what I get:

[image]

I've tried changing blur style to all the available values, tried toggling Vibrancy, but no avail. They either make the background almost totally white, black, or make the visual effect view totally transparent (when I click Vibrancy), but I don't get the correct effect.

How can I get visual effect view to display correctly just as in Interface Builder?

Comment: Check, Settings - General - Accessibility - Reduce Transparency from device.

Comment: @Desdenova I'm on simulator, not device. It's a plain fresh simulator, I haven't messed with any settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was just the simulator (for some weird reason). I've tried it on real device and it displays just fine on device.